# If $x^3 - x > 0$, so $x > - 1$. How do I prove that by contrapositive?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, discrete-mathematics, inequality, proof-writing

My attempt:

$Q \implies P$, by contrapositive we have: $\neg Q \implies \neg P$, so, if $x < - 1$, $x^3 - x < 0$

I don't know how to finish. Can someone help me?

Comment: The contrapositive is: If $x \leq -1$, then $x^3-x \leq 0$ (no strict inequalities). **Hint**: factorize $x^3-x = (x^2-1)x$. What can you say about the signs of the two factors for $x \leq -1$?

Comment: @AndreasLenz I really don't know. Could you please explain? I am really a beginner with maths

Comment: *Hint*: A quadratic polynomial has sign  opposite to the sign of its leading coefficient between its roots (if any), the sign of its leading coefficient out side the interval of the roots.

Comment: You could factor $x^3 - x$ as $x(x + 1)(x - 1)$, then examine the sign of each factor in the interval $(-\infty, -1]$.

Comment: The contrapositive of $Q\Rightarrow P$ is $\neg P\Rightarrow\neg Q$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First, if not $a > b$, then $a \leq b$.  There are three ordering states: less than, equal, and greater than.  If we assert that one is not the case, then the other two remain.  So, from
$$  x^3 - x > 0 \implies x > -1  $$
the contrapositive is (notice the exchange of the two clauses as we negate them)
$$  \neg (x > -1) \implies \neg (x^3 - x > 0)  $$
and using the properties of inequalities, this simplifies to
$$  x \leq -1 \implies x^3 - x \leq 0  \text{.}  $$

Factoring, we obtain
$$  x \leq -1 \implies x(x^2 - 1) \leq 0  \text{.}  $$
Notice that our assumption forces $x$ to be negative.  This means the first factor, $x$, is negative.  For the second factor,

- if $x^2 > 1$, the second factor is positive,
- if $x^2 = 1$, the second factor is zero, and
- if $x^2 < 1$, the second factor is negative.

The assumed inequality, $x \leq -1$ gives us two cases: $x < -1$ or $x = -1$.

- ($x = -1$ case)  If $x = -1$, then $x^2 = 1$ and the second factor is $0$, so $x(x^2-1) = (-1)(0) = 0$, which is compatible with $x(x^2-1) \leq 0$.
- ($x < -1$ case)  If $x < -1$, then $|x| > 1$, so $x^2 > 1$, so $x(x^2 - 1)$ is the product of a negative and a positive number, so is negative, which is compatible with $x(x^2 - 1) \leq 0$.

Combining the two cases, we have shown the validity of $x \leq -1 \implies x^3 - x \leq 0$.

Comment: Thank you so much:DDD I did understand part of it, and i'm gonna try to get the rest. Thanks again:D

Answer (score 0):

Take the simpler route:

Suppose that, $x^3-x>0$, but $x≤-1$. Then we have:

- If $x=-1$, then $x^3-x=0$.

A contradiction.

- If $x<-1$, then $x<0$ and $x^2>1$. This implies, $x^2-1>0$.
  This means, $x(x^2-1)=x^3-x<0$.

Again a contradiction.

Therefore, if $x^3-x>0$, then $x>-1$.